# Can't figure out sass loader for webpack and ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, webpack, sass-loader

I am trying to use .scss for my stylesheets in my ReactJS app. 
I have a webpack config file with `css-loader , sass-loader, and style-loader.`

I was able to import css into my app.js file with `import './test.css'` however i've had no luck with `import './test.scss'`?

Here's my package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.7.7",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "checkbox.css": "^1.1.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "eslint": "^2.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^5.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.16.1",
    "node-sass": "^3.7.0",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "sass-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  }
```

My webpack:

```
  module:{
    loaders:[
      {test:/\.js$/,exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader'},
      {test:/\.scss$/, loaders:['style','css','sass']},
      // {test:/\.css$/, loader: 'style!css', exclude: /node_modules/},
      {test:/\.html$/, loader: 'raw-loader'}
    ]
  },
```

****The 3rd line is commented out because I figured out how to load css.**

in my app.js

I've tried `require("!style!css!sass!./styles.scss");`
and have also tried `import './styles.scss'` with no success.

Currently my error is `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./../../node_modules/css-loader/lib/css-base.js"`

Comment: Can you share the stack trace with us?

Answer (score 6):

Your webpack config is okay but you are missing [node-sass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass) library in order to be able to use sass-loader as you can see in the [sass-loader documentation](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader).

To fix it, install the library

```
npm install node-sass --save-dev
```

Comment: Thank you, I installed node-sass, and I am still getting the same error. :(

Answer (score 1):

Your config looks ok, but the error suggests there's an issue with the css loader package. I would try reinstalling it with `npm i css-loader` just in case.

You would import scss with `import './file.scss'`, no additional loader settings needed via `require`.

If that won't work, feel free to ping me with a sample git repo that i can clone and run.

Comment: Hey @Grgur Thank you. I reinstalled css-loader but now my error is `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./test.scss"`

Comment: @Grgur I'm having this issue with the aspnet integration. There's steps on how to reproduce this on this issue, and also other people with the same problem: https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/132#issuecomment-239179330. Maybe you could take a look? :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the error.

In my app.js I had to write `import '!style!css!sass!./test.scss'`
instead of `import './test.scss'`. This cleared up the error, which was very confusing because for css files I could just write `import './test.css` without the use of `!css!` prepended.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your scss files extensions to sass. Apparently, sass-loader would figure out the style you want to use from the file extension. That's how i managed to fix it.
Alternatively, use indentedSyntax option for sass-loader :

`loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass?indentedSyntax']`